# HLSL Depth buffer. Identify when a piexel is about to replace another at shader runtime

Tags: buffer, hlsl, clipping, depth

I cannot find any useful info about the Depth Buffer and how it works. I know you can turn it on and off, but is it possible to do it at the shader runtime, in the PiexelShaderFunction? When does the clipping occur? Before the Pixel Shader starts? What if I want to track the event of clipping in the PiexelShaderFunction and do something when it happens?

Ideally i need the following system:

```
    PixelShaderFunction
    {
    //... some code.
    if (clipping)
        return (0,0,value1,value2);
    else
        return(value1,value2,0,0);
    }
```

What i came up with from the top of my head is:

```
    PixelShaderFunction
    {
    //... some code.
    if (value1%2 == 0)
        return (0,0,value1,value2);
    else
        return(value1,value2,0,0);
    }
```

Which gives me 50% precision and is a good alternative, but I am forced to draw my scene twice because I need it to be drawn with depth stencil turned off first and then with the stencil turned on. If I could at least turn it on and off at PiexelShaderFunction at runtime that would help immensely, not to say that I still need to know if the clipping occurs.

Edit: I've just read that "Write masks control what data gets written to a render target. The output write masks control on a per-render target, per-component level what data gets written to the render target(s)." Does it mean that I can specify which of the several render targets I have can use depth buffer and what cannot? If yes, how can I do it in XNA?

More: How exactly is Stencil Buffer filled, and how exactly can you control it? How does it influence the depth buffer? Please if someone has links to examples, give them to me! MSDN is so sparse!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the doc of the [graphics pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) depth-testing is applied after the pixelshader. But there is a technique called early-z-rejection ([source](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch29.html)), which performs the depthcheck before the pixelshader. Summarizing, you can't determine directly, whether a fragment is culled or not in the pixelshader.

Two workarounds came into my mind:

1. Render a depth-pre-pass into a rendertarget. This texture you could use while rendering, to determine the depth in the pixelshader.
2. Render your geometry two times, one time with the normal depth function, another time with the reversed depth function (`D3DRS_ZFUNC`([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))). You only need to change the color in the pixelshader regarding the step you are rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Basically my main goal is to ensure that I DO NOT render my geometry twice). If I render it twice I have no problems (almost:)). Could you tell me please why on Earth do they clip the pixel after the pixel shader. They could gain performance by NOT processing that pixel. Or maybe you CAN DO something with this about-to-be-clipped pixel? Mb force-return something :)?

Comment: One more thing, is there a way to access depth buffer like a render target after you have drawn a scene?

Comment: I think they culled the fragments after, because you can manipulate the depth of a fragment in the pixelshader. Since newer implementations the early z-rejection after the rasterizer is used if the depth isn't manipulated and saves some performance. But if a fragment is culled it never reaches the shader, so you can't react. Since DX10 it is possible to access the depth buffer directly: http://bitwisegames.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/getting-direct-access-to-the-depthbuffer-in-directx10/. In DX9 you have to work with MRTs or a depth pre-pass.